# r: combine filter with n_distinct in data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

Simple question. Considering the data frame below, I want to count distinct IDs: one for all records and one after filtering on status. However, the `%>%` doesn't seem to work here. I just want to have a single value as ouput (so for `total` this should be 10, for `closed` it should be 5), not a dataframe . Both # lines don't work

```
dat <- data.frame (ID = as.factor(c(1:10)),
                   status = as.factor(rep(c("open","closed"))))


total <- n_distinct(dat$ID)
#closed <- dat %>% filter(status == "closed") %>% n_distinct(dat$ID)
#closed <- dat %>% filter(status == "closed") %>% n_distinct(ID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n_distinct` expects a vector as input, you are passing a dataframe. You can do :

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  filter(status == "closed") %>%
  summarise(n = n_distinct(ID))

#  n
#1 5
```

Or without using `filter` :

```
dat %>% summarise(n = n_distinct(ID[status == "closed"]))
```

You can add `%>% pull(n)` to above if you want a vector back and not a dataframe.

Comment: Thanks!. The %>% pull(n) did the job

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[status == "closed"][, .(n = uniqueN(ID))]
```